# Java Program for reading and writing text files

Tags: java

I have a file with multiple lines. My java program must read each three lines from it and format them in one row and writes it to another file. How I can tell to ignore some lines in the file?

For example:
File that program reads from:

> First,second,third
>  
>   Blas,Blad,Blaff,
>   Mop,Mp,Sup

It must turn this three lines to:

> First,Sup,Blaff

It does it correct, but how I can tell to program to ignore some lines that have particular words, for example, if it has particular word, like "sub" in one of the lines?

The example of the code is below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String text = "";
    String changedText = "";
    String first = "", second = "", third = "";
    int outerCounter = 0;
    int innerCounter = 0;
    int arturCounter = 0;
    String temp = "";

    //first, we read data from file
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("test.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    input.useDelimiter("\r");

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        text = input.next();

        outerCounter += 1;
        innerCounter = 0;
        for (String string : text.split(",")) {

            innerCounter += 1;
            if(outerCounter == 1) {
                second = string;
                break;
            }
            else if(outerCounter == 2 && innerCounter == 3) {

                third = string;
        }
            else if(outerCounter == 3 && innerCounter == 3) {
                first = string;
                outerCounter = 0;
                second = second.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""); //very important part, solves the problem with new line! 
                changedText += second + "," + first + "," + third + "\r" + "\n";
            }
        }


    }

    //second, we write obtained data to another file
    //PrintWriter creates the file
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("testOutput.txt");

    //write formatted output to the file
    output.println(changedText);

    //close the file
    output.close();
    System.out.println(changedText);

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you clarify exactly what your input is and how it should be output? What is the transformation you are looking to do?

Comment: `if (text.contains("sub")) { continue; }`, by the way, in your case you should use `input.nextLine()` rather than `input.next()`.

Comment: Well, ControlAltDel, what confused you?@Jaroslaw seems not have that problem. Thanks for feedback Jaroslaw. I don't understand why my question gets negative rate, I'm just a beginner, stackoverflow community like a vultures attacked my innocent attempt to get help

Comment: @Trex87, This community tries hard to NOT act like vultures or indulge in flame wars and does try hard to welcome new members. But there is often a backlash against questions that look a lot like you are asking us to help you complete a homework assignment. You can ask questions that help you complete homework but they need to be focussed on programming problems. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I would follow the paradigm:

- Init an array pos pointer. Say (p) = 0.
- Init an array. Say (arr) = []
- Create a function to read the next line, name it (a)
- Go into a loop.
- Call a() to get the next line, say (l) the new line.
- Check if EOF
- Check (l) for "invalid" words if one found call continue the loop to get the next line
- Add the line to (arr)[p] and increment p by one.
- If p == 3 write to file (arr)[0] + (arr)[2] + (arr)[1]. Reset (p) = 0.
- Else continue;